# Finding column-wise ranks of values in a multidimensional list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I often have to find ranks of values in a list. However, *Mathematica* does not have built-in functions for that, or may be I'm just not aware of them. I can easily find ranks of a row/column vector. For example, if I have

```
list1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10] ;
```

then `Ordering[Ordering[list1]]` gives me its rank. I have also written a following function that does my job.

```
 Rankme[list_] := Module[{rank},
  rank = ConstantArray[0, Length[list]];
  rank[[Ordering[list]]] = Range[1, Length[list]] ;
  rank
  ]
```

`Rankme[list1]` gives me ranks of values in the list1 . However, I am trying to find column-wise ranks of a list that has more than one column. For example, I have

```
list2 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 5}];
```

I want to find column-wise ranks of values in the list2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rrF = Ordering@Ordering@# &;
crF = Transpose[rrF /@ Transpose[#]] &;

mat = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 5}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mat, crF@mat}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using the function `colMap` suggested by @Mr.Wizard in the comments

```
colMap[f_][m_?MatrixQ] := (f /@ (m\[Transpose]))\[Transpose] 
(* or Transpose[fn /@ Transpose[m]] *)

colMap[rrF][mat] // MatrixForm
```

gives same output as `crF@mat` above.

Comment: Thank you kguler. May be I owe you a couple of cups of coffee.

Comment: incidentally consider a reusable function `colMap[fn_][m_?MatrixQ] := (fn /@ (m\[Transpose]))\[Transpose]` (+1)

Comment: ramesh, my pleasure. One cup -quad espresso- would be fine:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, great idea, thank you. Will update with the `colMap` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ordering /@ Transpose[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{10}], {3, 4}]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It was easy.

Comment: If it doesn't give you what you want, please explain why.